# AWK invoking sh instead of csh

Tags: awk, csh

I'm sure there is a much easier way to do this, so I'm all ears.

```
sort -nrk 7 my_list.tsv | tail -n 1 | awk '{print("setenv INPUT_DIR `pwd`/"$1)}'
```

The first item in my .tsv are filenames (sorted) that I'm trying to set as an environmental variable in csh. I want to add the pull the path too. I though this would work but...

```
sh: setenv: command not found
```

Even though I'm in csh. Can I get the awk system function to use csh/tcsh?

J

Comment: The script you posted has nothing to do with the awk system() command so is your question about that script or about system()?

Answer (score 0):

'to add the pull the path too'. ??

Do you mean

```
       echo "fileName" | awk '{printf("setenv '`pwd`'/%s\n", $1)}'
```

output

```
       setenv INPUT_DIR /home/shellter/filename
```

I've replaced your `sort ... | tail ..` as that doesn't seem to be your core question.

Also note that the single-quotes prevent the back-quote command-substitution being processed. You turn off the single-quotes, get your cmd-sub value, the turn single-quotes back on again.

If this not what you mean, please edit your question and replace `sort ... tail ...` as above with a simple echo "string", AND include the expected output. It will also help to include the output you are currently getting.

To answer the question in your headline, awk is almost certainly using the value stored in the $SHELL environment variable. Or there may be another variable, so do a `set | grep /bin/sh` and `setenv | grep /bin/sh` so see where the reference to `/bin/sh` is getting set. Then decide how you're going manage that.

When I run your code, I don't get any indication that the shell was executed. I get

```
setenv INPUT_DIR `pwd`/file
```

but I'm running the code under ksh. I don't have a csh to use test with. But for the given case, it shouldn't matter.

IHTH